# moving elements in same container

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to get information if below code is undefined behavior, I did read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move).

In particular I want to be sure that iterator variable `iter` will be valid in cases where moved elements overlap destination range.

I think this is not good but can't confirm, and what would be better way to do this?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // move 3, 4 closer to beginning
    std::vector<int> vec { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    auto iter = std::move(vec.begin() + 2, vec.end() - 3, vec.begin() + 1);
    std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
}
```

also there is no reference to what this `iter` is supposed to point at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's well-formed to use [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move#Notes) for this case.

(emphasis mine)

> When moving overlapping ranges, **`std::move` is appropriate when moving
>   to the left (beginning of the destination range is outside the source
>   range)** while `std::move_backward` is appropriate when moving to the
>   right (end of the destination range is outside the source range).

And about the return value,

> Output iterator to the element past the last element moved `(d_first + (last - first))`

So `iter` points to the element following the last element moved, i.e.

```
// elements of vec (after moved)
// 1, 3, 4, x, 5, 6, 7
// here     ^
```

Note that

> After this operation the elements in the moved-from range will still
>   contain valid values of the appropriate type, but not necessarily the
>   same values as before the move.

Here, `x` is such an unspecified value. This will probably happen to be another `4`, but this shouldn't be relied upon. Subtle changes, such as a vector of strings instead of numbers, can cause different behavior. For example, the same operation on `{ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven" }` would probably result in it being `"two"` rather than the `"four"` you might expect from seeing the numeric example.

Comment: While the function isn't UB there, it seems fishy to me so I wouldn't call it "fine". The result of the move will be `{1, 3, 4, unspecified, 5, 6, 7}`, and `iter` is pointing to the unspecified value.

Comment: yes, I took a read and it says `"After this operation the elements in the moved-from range will still contain valid values of the appropriate type, but not necessarily the same values as before the move."`

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I got what you want to say; I think it's fine for this specified case, i.e. for `int`.

Comment: It might be worth putting a warning about that in your answer. For example, when I did this on strings instead of numbers, `{ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven" }` turned into `{ "one", "three", "four", "two", "five", "six", "seven" }`.

Comment: I'm more interested what will happen if vector is sorted and this element isn't removed manually? I guess you lose control over the vector then.

Comment: @metablaster It depends on your intent, e.g. you might use `std::copy` instead.

Comment: or `std::rotate`